# How to extract text between two delimiters in a string in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have following string, how can I extract the text that lies between the two delimiters:

`some text to be extracted` :

```
text text text text

= = = = = = = = = = = = =

some text to be extracted

= = = = = = = = = = = = =

text text text text
```

I want also the two delimiters to be returned with the text.
how can this be done with Objective-C ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it.

You have to find all the ranges where your delimiter strings are.

Then you take ranges 2 by 2 to extract your string between them :

```
    NSString *str = @"text text text text --- some text to be extracted... --- text text text text";

    NSString *myDelimiterString = @"---";

    NSMutableArray *arrayOfRangeForOccurrences = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSUInteger length = [str length];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length);
    while(range.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        range = [str rangeOfString:myDelimiterString options:0 range:range];
        if(range.location != NSNotFound)
        {    
            [arrayOfRangeForOccurrences addObject:[NSValue valueWithRange:range]];
            range = NSMakeRange(range.location + range.length, length - (range.location + range.length));
        }
    }

    //at least 2 delimiters have been found, we can extract a string
    if (arrayOfRangeForOccurrences.count >= 2) {
        //Extracting first text :
        NSRange firstRangeForDelimiter = [[arrayOfRangeForOccurrences objectAtIndex:0] rangeValue];
        NSRange secondRangeForDelimiter = [[arrayOfRangeForOccurrences objectAtIndex:1]rangeValue];

        NSRange rSub = NSMakeRange(firstRangeForDelimiter.location + firstRangeForDelimiter.length, secondRangeForDelimiter.location - firstRangeForDelimiter.location - firstRangeForDelimiter.length);
        NSString *myExtractedText = [str substringWithRange:rSub];
        NSLog(@"myExtractedText is : %@", myExtractedText);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No pair of delimiter found");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like below line of code,

```
NSArray *arrChars = [@"Your,String,for,test" componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

So you will get parts of string separated by ,.

Hope this may help you for what you want.